Supabase trigger NEW reference to autogenerated ID is null
In supabase I have a trigger that triggers after INSERT at table x:
demo at db-fiddle
----for tests on vanilla PostgreSQL, off Supabase
--create schema auth;
--create function auth.uid()returns uuid return gen_random_uuid();

create table public.x(
  id int generated by default as identity primary key
, x_name text);

create table public.user_x(
    user_id uuid
  , x_id int references public.x(id)
  , user_role text);

create function add_user_x()
returns trigger language plpgsql as '
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.user_x (user_id, x_id, user_role)
    VALUES (auth.uid(), NEW.id, ''owner'');
    return NEW;
END';

This is the trigger definition:
CREATE TRIGGER add_user_x 
AFTER INSERT ON public.x
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION add_user_x()

Now my problem is that the "user_id" and "user_role" fields work fine in the insert, but for the "x_id" variable only a NULL is inserted. The ID of x gets autogenerated using the default supabase "gen_random_uuid ()" function and it works fine in the "x" table.
Could the issue be that the NEW object that I reference to does not yet contain the autogenerated ID field? How could I fix this issue and make sure that the x_id column of my user_x table gets filled by the trigger?

Needs more information, to your question add as text the complete trigger function and trigger definition. My best guess is you are using a for statement trigger where NEW/OLD is  NULL.

@AdrianKlaver Thanks for your comment! I added the trigger definition and the complete function definition. Everything else is handled by supabase as far as I can see.


You obviously did not read the entire comment: My best guess is you are using a for statement trigger where NEW/OLD is NULL.. Then there are the docs plpgsql trigger: NEW record new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations. 2) You still have not included the entire function definition. Details matter.


Off-topic: did you check row level security? Might be easier and more secure

@FrankHeikens I think the presence of auth.uid() in their original example suggests they do use RLS, because Supabase Auth relies on it. My bet why they don't put that user id straight into the x row and use that for ownership is they want x's to be co-owned and/or for each x they need more roles than just owner, which role column would suggest. There's probably a subquery from an RLS policy later that checks this role.

Statement-level triggers require that you define an alias for the transition relations explicitly.
From CREATE TRIGGER doc:

The REFERENCING option enables collection of transition relations, which are row sets that include all of the rows inserted, deleted, or modified by the current SQL statement. This feature lets the trigger see a global view of what the statement did, not just one row at a time. (...) NEW TABLE may only be specified once, and only for a trigger that can fire on UPDATE or INSERT; it creates a transition relation containing the after-images of all rows updated or inserted by the statement.

And as already quoted by @Adrian Klaver from 43.10.1. Triggers on Data Changes:

When a PL/pgSQL function is called as a trigger, several special variables are created automatically in the top-level block. They are:

NEW record
new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.


Makes sense, because it's a singular, scalar record, and statement-level triggers should see a whole table or an array of those, rather than just one.
The change that would get rid of your error is pretty minor: add the referencing clause, and replace the insert..values in the trigger function, with an insert..select..from, using the transition relation that holds all newly generated id's:
demo at db-fiddle
create function add_user_x()returns trigger language plpgsql as '
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.user_x (user_id, x_id, user_role)
    SELECT auth.uid(), new_table.id, ''owner''
    FROM new_table;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END';


CREATE TRIGGER add_user_x 
AFTER INSERT ON public.x 
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table --mandatory
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION add_user_x()

Now you can see that in response to an insert into x, the user_x table gets a new record with the x_id correctly populated based on incoming x:
insert into x(x_name)values('x_1');
select * from user_x;




user_id
x_id
user_role




b2bba742-f299-4cd8-8ed4-5070b9ff84e5
1
owner



And the table can now be joined on that foreign key:
select*from x join user_x on x.id=user_x.x_id;




id
x_name
user_id
x_id
user_role




1
x_1
b2bba742-f299-4cd8-8ed4-5070b9ff84e5
1
owner



Another way to fix this would be to downgrade to a row-level trigger, which you could do by simply swapping out for each statement for for each row and leaving everything else unaltered, but this is a good use case for statement-level triggers. They'll perform way better and fire just once.
